# Jackson XML mapper forcing lowercase XML tags

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

I am trying to convert a POJO with XMLElement annotations into an XML string. I have made the variable names capitalized and the annotation names are also capitalized.

When I run the code snippet below I wind up with the XML example below, all the tag names are lowercase. I have been experimenting with enabling/disabling features but have not found anything that would turn on/off forcing lower case XML tag out.

```
Value of String xml variable below:
ACTUAL OUTPUT:
<root><field1>value</field1><field2>value2<field2><field3>value3<field3><root>

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
<root><Field1>value</Field1><Field2>value2<Field2><Field3>value3<Field3><root>


public class Object1 {
    @XmlElement(name = "Field1", required = true)
    protected String Field1;
    @XmlElement(name = "Field2", required = true)
    protected String Field2;
    @XmlElement(name = "Field3", required = true)
    protected String Field3;
}

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.JacksonXmlModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

...


JacksonXmlModule xmlModule = new JacksonXmlModule();
xmlModule.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(xmlModule);
xmlMapper.disable( MapperFeature.USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING );

// convert the object into xml string
// object1 is an instance of Object1 above with assigned values 
String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(object1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution,
but perhaps not the answer you are seeking.

Replace the `@XmlElement` annotations with `@JacksonXmlProperty` annotations.
Use the `localName` attribute to set the tag name.

Here is an example:
`@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Field1")`

Comment: That worked. Thanks, one follow up if you don't mind. The fields are now duping, one capitalized and one camel case. Any thoughts on what might cause that?

Comment: The localName that you define in the `JacksonXmlProperty` annotation is the value that Jackson uses.  I tested with version 2.9.9 of jackson-dataformat-xml.

Comment: Thanks, for future readers turns out my duplicate issue was similar to what is discussed here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1609. I had capitalized my object variable names as an experiment to fix the larger capitalization issue. Once I put my field names back and relied on the JacksonXmlProperty annotation I was fine.